# PHP string with special characters returns wrong answer

Tags: php, regex, string

I have these two lines in my code:

```
$pattern = "/<p class=\"prev [first]*\"><a href=\"\/photography\/photo-of-the-day\/[^\/]+/";
echo $pattern;
```

and the output is just:

```
/
```

I even tried that like this:

```
$pattern = '/<p class="prev [first]*"><a href="\/photography\/photo-of-the-day\/[^\/]+/';
echo $pattern;
```

but I got the same output.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Well what is your expected output ?

Comment: <p class="prev [first]*"><a href="\/photography\/photo-of-the-day\/[^\/]+

Comment: That is because you're seeing output in browser rendering HTML. Do `view source` to see full pattern.

Comment: Hint: _open HTML source code_ (Ctrl+U in FF). Your browser will interpret this output as HTML and, thus, you'll not able to see <p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was seeing the output in browser and so it was rendered by browser and I wasn't able to see the content. Looking at the page source in browser is the way I can see my expected output.